# How do I get or create message_id for yammer api?

Tags: json, yammer

We are successfully integrating our application with Yammer's embedded features and action buttons.  However, our business partners don't like the embedded buttons and would rather use our own to like and follow articles.

I have read through the REST API documention for yammer but it doesn't tell me how to find the message_id of the article the users want to like or follow.  Am I missing something?

POST https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/liked_by/current.json?message_id=[:id]

DELETE https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/liked_by/current.json?message_id=[:id]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/open_graph_objects?url= [HTMLEncodedAddress] will return the message_id I need to like or follow an article

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the timestamp of a message to get the permalink.  The message_id is the threadid parameter in the url, e.g https://www.yammer.com/[yournetworkname]/#/Threads/show?threadId=123456789

Comment: That may work if we used static pages but we dynamically generate articles using IBM's WCM technology and we need to figure out how to pass a message_id of a new article that's been authored so users can like and/or follow the article.  Is there a way to look up the message_id of a new article?  The articles already have an embedded feed so users can comment

Answer (score 0):

Did you post the generated message using yammer's RESTful API? If so, you should get the message_id in the http response as a json object.

Comment: No, we use the embedded feed function to allow users to post comments about an article.  Is there anyway to retrieve the message ID from the embedded feed?

Comment: We aren't trying to allow users to like other user messages.  We want to allow users to like and follow articles from our app.